# unsupported MONO function " System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(bool)" using UNITY3D and MATLAB's MWARRAY.DLL

Tags: c#, matlab, mono, unity-game-engine, windows-identity

the problem starts with a function call to a mono function that is not supported yet. the call is made from a close matlab DLL called MWARRAY.DLL (.net version 2.x), this dll is normally used with VS .NET and is working if you use .net 3.5.

the function is :  [mscorlib]System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity::GetCurrent(bool)

I can think of a few possible solution, but i am not sure how to do them:

1. decompile dll and replace byte code with a similar and working function: [mscorlib]System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity::GetCurrent() 
   notice that there is no boolean passed to the function
2. compile mono and write the function myself
3. using an old version of MWARRAY.DLL (couldnt find, but might still use the same code)

for the decompilation i used IDA. 
i found the location where there is a call to the first function, CIL + HEX below

```
loc_38B1:    
ldsfld  native     
int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::Zero   
stloc.s 7    
ldc.i4.0
stloc.s 8
ldc.i4.1
stloc.s 9
ldc.i4.1
call    class [mscorlib]System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity::GetCurrent(bool)
stloc.s 0xA
call    void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::PrepareConstrainedRegions()
  .try {
ldc.i4.0
stloc.s 0xB
br      loc_3982
```

**the HEX of the call and stloc commands:**

```
28 96 00 00 0A
```

**i also compiled and decompiled my own dll, with calls to both functions just to see how the other command looks in byte code:**

```
loc_3AE:
call    class [mscorlib]System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity [mscorlib]System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity::GetCurrent()
callvirt class System.String [mscorlib]System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity::get_Name()
stloc.s 8
ldc.i4.1
```

**hex of the custom compiled/decompiled lines in  bold:**

```
28  00 00 0A 6F 1B 00 00 0A  13 08 17
```

i would like to know if anyone has an idea of the proposed solution paths, or anything else that might come in mind ?

Comment: Mono assemblies (MSCORLIB) are most probably signed, and so they cannot be tampered with (ruling out option #1). Also, relying on code that was compiled for a different environment may lead to other issues (what if the code uses 5 more unimplemented Mono methods? What if you discover this 2 months from now? is it really worth to rely on this functionality?)

Comment: i will fix all 5 of them obviously. i will never know if i dont try it first.

Comment: and i dont need to change mscorelib, i just need to change mwarray.dll.

Comment: My point was you're relying on a library that is not very robust in this particular scenario. Maybe you should think of which functionality you need from this library and look it in some other library.

Comment: its too much work to port my code. it is functional and very fast.

Comment: btw the mwarray.dll cant be replaced.

Comment: The other method overload (without the boolean) doesn't do the same thing, so i doubt you can safely replace the code to use it (even if the replacement is technically possible).

Comment: after extracting the project with reflector, and compiling it (thanks lior), i found out that the overloaded method doesnt work, so i assigned a null. the code knows how to deal with a null value so it passes without an exception.

Comment: Hey ori, I am having the exact same issue as you. I tried your solution but I could not edit the line or save the new dll using reflexil. Could you please answer my question about this with more details about how you solved this? thanks!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247389/how-to-use-reflexil-to-change-a-single-line-of-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has been solved.

using .net reflector to extract mwarray.dll it is possible to change the code from inside visual studio.

in class MCR() around line 330 there is a call to getcurrent(). replace with =null;